# FineUploader POST pending in Internet Explorer

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm having an issue with FineUploader in IE11.  My page works fine when I upload files after the initial load with no issues at all for any files.  However, if I leave the page open for 5 minutes without any activity, the next time I try to upload a file, it fails.  In the Developer Tools, all I see for the upload request is (Pending...) for protocol, method, and result.  Sometimes, it will freeze the browser completely, but other times, it just says "Processing..." on the screen.  This is a Ajax POST call.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The "processing..." message indicates that Fine Uploader is waiting for a response from your server after sending the last chunk of a chunked file. If Fine Uploader is stuck here, then your server is failing to return a response. This seems to be confirmed by your observations of the network request status in dev tools.

Sounds like an issue with your server, or perhaps some sort of browser plug-in. I'm not able to reproduce myself following your steps on IE11. Your next course of action is to look more closely at your server and how it is handling requests in this scenario. If you are seeing any error messages in the developer tools console that suggest Fine Uploader is at fault, please either comment here or open up an issue in the GitHub project's issue tracker.

Comment: I have narrowed down the issue somewhat to be able to replicate it consistently now.  If I upload files on the page when it first loads, it works fine and never "freezes."  However, if I leave the page open for 5-10 minutes and then go back to upload a file with multiple chunks, it freezes in the middle (it can get through 5 or 6 chunks, but freezes at 75% for some reason).  I have concurrent chunking turned OFF.  This only happens in IE (testing in IE11).  I guess it could be something on the server side, but the issue never happens in Chrome or Firefox.